# Applescript check if folder is true

Tags: applescript

in the below script i trying to determine if the inputed path points to a folder by checking:

```
folder of file_info -> should return true/false
```

but when trying this the script gives and error and stops.

but other values work fine example:

```
size of file_info -> return size incase of folder its "missing value"
```

someone knows why this doest work? i have seen other scripts where people use it, but no one seems to get this error

```
on log_event(themessage)
            set theLine to (do shell script "date  +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'" as string) & " " & themessage
            do shell script "echo " & theLine & " >> ~/Library/Logs/tvshowscript-events-test.log"
        end log_event

        tell application "Finder"

            set str to "Macintosh HD:Users:"

            set the_item to str as alias

            set file_info to get info for the_item

            my log_event("-------------- " & size of the file_info)
            my log_event("-------------- " & kind of the file_info)
            my log_event("-------------- " & folder of the file_info)   

        end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the lines `tell application "Finder"` and `end tell`.

Comment: thank you that works :) now going to work around that XD, to bad you can't even call a method inside the tell finder to get the value